# How to refresh webview instead of custom HTML

Tags: java, android-webview

I have customized my Page Not Available with HTML file in WebView to show when there is no internet.
It is working alright, but my problem is that, when the internet is reconnected and if i swipe to refresh the WebView page, it rather refreshes the HTML (page not available) page instead of the WebView page.

Below is my Java code.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you show a message at the bottom of your html? And check if the connection is restored with JS instead of java?

Comment: Nice idea! Please can you explain how to do that?